# Oscillating an object left and right based on it's current orientation

Tags: physics, javascript

I'm currently implementing a fire animation in HTML5 Canvas using the phone's accelerometer.

Regardless of the phones orientation, the triangles for the fire move upward. So you can spin your phone around to what ever degree you wish, and the triangles will move towards the sky.

My issue is trying to implement an oscillation left and right for these triangles. Before I had the accelerometer hooked up, I just applied an oscillation to the x axis and everything worked fine. Now however because the triangles are moving in what ever direction up is, I need to somehow apply the oscillation to both axis depending on what the orientation of the phone is.

Could anyone help me out?

I'm using JS for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were going to do it, I'd use (a very small subset of) vector math.

First, generate the desired deflection in "device-space". The following diagram uses two slerps. You can think of this as "starting at" UP and then pulling away from it, towards REFERENCE by +- 10%. Reference is calculated by "starting at" FLATREFERENCE and moving toward UP.

[image]

If you spin FLATREFERENCE around UP (a flat circle) and keep final slerp constant at 0, a spiral of triangles is produced along the perimeter of a cone, where the radius of the cone is set by REFERENCE. If you also vary final slerp randomly, then the cone's interior is filled. If FLATREFERENCE is fixed and final slerp varies randomly, a directional "spread" of triangles is produced ranging from -REFERENCE to +REFERENCE.

After you compute your normalized random direction (by any means), rotate it in 3D-space according to your accelerometer input. An "accelerometer", in this context, refers to both the physical device and the software/firmware that reads it and converts it into a convenient format - likely a "down" vector or Euler angles. You can use vector math again to just rotate the randomized vector by the accelerometer's rotation. World-Space "UP" is locked to Accelerometer-Space "UN-FORWARD".

[image]